Как настроить WireGuard на DDWRT?
Я правильно понимаю, что роутер выступает сам как сервер WG, а чтобы соединиться к внешнему серверу добавляется пир на роутере через который и происходит соединение клиентов через этот роутер?
Если да, то может кто поделиться конкретной информацией, как это сделать для собственного сервера WG?
